# Node RED & NodeJs on CentOS7 startup fails / server unavailable

Tags: node.js, centos7, node-red

I have a problem with Node-RRED on CentOS7.
I tried it on different machines, and followed the instructions on the webside. That brings me to the point, that the error is on my side.

This are the steps I followed:

```
curl --silent --location https://rpm.nodesource.com/setup_4.x | bash -
yum -y install nodejs
yum install gcc-c++ make
npm install -g --unsafe-perm node-red
```

Start:

```
node-red
```

After the start the console is standing on this line, as example

```
25 Feb 22:51:10 - [info] Server now running at http://127.0.0.1:1880/
```

In the documentation there should be more.I also tried with different browsers on this server address http://127.0.0.1:1880/ without success.

So what did I miss?

Comment: 127.0.0.1 is localhost, it's only accessable from the same machine as the server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Node-RED has started correctly, the next step is to connect to the Node-RED console by pointing your browser at port 1880 on the machine.

The flow file name includes the name of the machine Node-RED is running on so in the example the machine name inst `noltop`, where as your machine is called `sampleserver.sampledomain.com`

Given that you say you have a minimal install (which doesn't have Web browser or X iirc) you will probably need to use a different machine to view the console.

e.g. http://sampleserver.sampledomain.com:1880